# Integrate counter in awk and lower value of specific column

Tags: awk, counter, tolower

I am trying to incorporate 2 functions into my `awk` command.
I want `tolower` the information in Col1 in a Column 2 (thus the information in Col1, will be the value of 2 cols - Col1 and Col2, with the values in `lower` in Col2) and I want to count from *1-N* that begins and ends with the start of certain markers that I have.

The data (tab-separated) currently looks like this:

```
<s>
He  PRP -
could   MD  -
tell    VB  -
she PRP -
was VBD -
teasing VBG -
him PRP -
.   .   .
</s>
<s>
He  PRP -
kept    VBD -
his PRP$    -
eyes    NNS -
closed  VBD -
,   ,   -
but CC  -
he  PRP -
could   MD  -
feel    VB  -
himself PRP -
smiling VBG -
.   .   .
</s>
```

The ideal output would be like this:

```
<s>
He  he  PRP 1
could   could   MD  2
tell    tell    VB  3
she     she PRP 4
was was VBD     5
teasing teasing VBG 6
him him PRP 7
.   .   .   8
</s>
<s>
He  he  PRP 1-
kept    kept    VBD 2
his his PRP$    3
eyes    eyes    NNS 4
closed  closed  VBD 5
,   ,   ,   6
but but CC  7
he  he  PRP 8
could   could   MD  9
feel    feel    VB  10
himself     himself PRP 11
smiling smiling VBG 12
.   .   .   13
</s>
```

The 2-step `awk` that I am trying that does not work is this:

Step 1:

```
awk '!NF{$0=x}1' input | awk '{$1=$1; print "<s>\n" $0 "\t.\n</s>"}' RS=  FS='\n' OFS='\t-\n' > output
```

Here, I do not know how to make the "-" into a counter

and Step 2 (which directly gives me an error):

```
awk '{print $1 "\t" '$1 = tolower($1)' "\t" $2 "\t" $3}' input > output
```

Any suggestions 1. on how to solved the lower and counter and 2. if it is possible to combine these two steps?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NF>1{$1=$1 FS tolower($1); $4=++f} NF==1{f=0}1' file
<s>
He he PRP - 1
could could MD - 2
tell tell VB - 3
she she PRP - 4
was was VBD - 5
teasing teasing VBG - 6
him him PRP - 7
. . . . 8
</s>
<s>
He he PRP - 1
kept kept VBD - 2
his his PRP$ - 3
eyes eyes NNS - 4
closed closed VBD - 5
, , , - 6
but but CC - 7
he he PRP - 8
could could MD - 9
feel feel VB - 10
himself himself PRP - 11
smiling smiling VBG - 12
. . . . 13
</s>
```

That is, set `$1` and `$4` on no `<s>` lines and reset the counter otherwise (yes, I know it is resetting twice but I cannot think on something neater right now). Then `1` to print normally.

Note you are playing a lot with `print` and the delimiters. It is best to just change the fields and let `print` happen automatically upon a True condition (`1`) and using the given field separators. A kind of model-view-controller : )

Comment: you can set `RS` to `</s>`

Comment: @karakfa yep, I tried that but then it was kind of breaking the format, so I preferred to go the old way. Thanks anyway!